# How to combine functions that don't return any specific values into a class

Tags: python, class, methods

The following two functions read and save the image in directory:

```
def resample(image, reference_image, def_value=0.0):
    return sitk.Resample(image,
                         reference_image,
                         sitk.Transform(),
                         sitk.sitkLinear,
                         def_value,
                         reference_image.GetPixelID())

def ResampleNiiSave(dcmPath, nrdPath):
    dcmItk = dicomread(dcmPath, imgitk=True) # contains one file multiple slice
    nrdItk = nrrdread(nrdPath, imgitk=True) # contains single nrrd file
    data = [dcmItk, None]
    if len(nrdItk.GetSize()) == 4:
        if nrdItk.GetSize()[3] == 3:
            for ig in range(3):
                imgnp = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(nrdItk)[ig, ...]
                imgItk = sitk.GetImageFromArray(imgnp)
                data[1] = imgItk
                nrdItkAl = resample(data[1], data[0])
                nrd2niiPath = os.path.splitext(nrdPath)[0]+'_{}'.format(ig)+'.nii.gz'
                if os.path.isfile(nrd2niiPath) is None:
                    sitk.WriteImage(nrdItkAl, nrd2niiPath)
                del imgnp, imgItk  # necessary?
        elif nrdItk.GetSize()[3] == 1:
            imgnp = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(nrdItk)
            imgnp = np.squeeze(imgnp)
            imgItk = sitk.GetImageFromArray(imgnp)
            data[1] = imgItk
            nrdItkAl = resample(data[1], data[0])
            nrd2niiPath = os.path.splitext(nrdPath)[0] + '.nii.gz'
            if os.path.isfile(nrd2niiPath) is None:
                sitk.WriteImage(nrdItkAl, nrd2niiPath)
            del imgnp, imgItk
        else:
            raise ValueError("image has unknown dimension")
    else:
        data[1] = nrdItk
        nrdItkAl = sitk.Resample(data[1], data[0], sitk.Transform(), sitk.sitkLinear,
                                 np.min(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(data[1])).astype('double'), data[1].GetPixelID())
        nrd2niiPath = os.path.splitext(nrdPath)[0] + '.nii.gz'
        if os.path.isfile(nrd2niiPath) is None:
            sitk.WriteImage(nrdItkAl, nrd2niiPath)
    dcm2niiPath = dcmPath+'.nii.gz'
    if os.path.isfile(dcm2niiPath) is None:
        sitk.WriteImage(dcmItk, dcm2niiPath)
```

The `ResampleNiiSave` function doesn't necessarily return any value, rather it performs alignment and saves the variables to another format.

How do I create a class to combine both functions as class methods. I tried the following with little luck:

```
class prepSeg:
    def __init__(self, dcmPath, nrdPath):
        self.dcmPath = dcmPath
        self.nrdPath = nrdPath

    def resample(self, image, reference_image, def_value=0.0):
        return sitk.Resample(image,
                             reference_image,
                             sitk.Transform(),
                             sitk.sitkLinear,
                             def_value,
                             reference_image.GetPixelID())

    def ResampleNiiSave(self):
        dcmItk = dicomread(self.dcmPath, imgitk=True) # contains one file multiple slice
        nrdItk = nrrdread(self.nrdPath, imgitk=True) # contains single nrrd file
        data = [dcmItk, None]
        if len(nrdItk.GetSize()) == 4:
            if nrdItk.GetSize()[3] == 3:
                for ig in range(3):
                    imgnp = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(nrdItk)[ig, ...]
                    imgItk = sitk.GetImageFromArray(imgnp)
                    data[1] = imgItk
                    nrdItkAl = self.resample(data[1], data[0])
                    nrd2niiPath = os.path.splitext(self.nrdPath)[0]+'_{}'.format(ig)+'.nii.gz'
                    if os.path.isfile(nrd2niiPath) is None:
                        sitk.WriteImage(nrdItkAl, nrd2niiPath)
                    del imgnp, imgItk  # necessary?
            elif nrdItk.GetSize()[3] == 1:
                imgnp = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(nrdItk)
                imgnp = np.squeeze(imgnp)
                imgItk = sitk.GetImageFromArray(imgnp)
                data[1] = imgItk
                nrdItkAl = self.resample(data[1], data[0])
                nrd2niiPath = os.path.splitext(self.nrdPath)[0] + '.nii.gz'
                if os.path.isfile(nrd2niiPath) is None:
                    sitk.WriteImage(nrdItkAl, nrd2niiPath)
                del imgnp, imgItk
            else:
                raise ValueError("image has unknown dimension")
        else:
            data[1] = nrdItk
            nrdItkAl = sitk.Resample(data[1], data[0], sitk.Transform(), sitk.sitkLinear,
                                     np.min(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(data[1])).astype('double'), data[1].GetPixelID())
            nrd2niiPath = os.path.splitext(self.nrdPath)[0] + '.nii.gz'
            if os.path.isfile(nrd2niiPath) is None:
                sitk.WriteImage(nrdItkAl, nrd2niiPath)
        dcm2niiPath = self.dcmPath+'.nii.gz'
        if os.path.isfile(dcm2niiPath) is None:
            sitk.WriteImage(dcmItk, dcm2niiPath)
```

Now, what should be the `return` for the `prepSeg` class. However I run `prepSeg` with two file paths inputs, it simply creates the class object but don't perform any of the tasks in the `resample` and `save`.
For example:

```
A = prepSeg(dcmFiles[-2],nrdFilesIdx[-2])
# .ResampleNiiSave()
# prepSeg.ResampleNiiSave
print(A)
A.ResampleNiiSave
```

returns:

```
prepSeg object at 0x0000025E6D96E710>
<bound method prepSeg.ResampleNiiSave of <prepSeg object at 0x0000025E6D96E710>>
```

Comment: `A.ResampleNiiSave()` you didn't actually called the function.

Comment: I ran that too at first but got the following error: 
----> 6 `A.ResampleNiiSave()`
`~\PycharmProjects\Codes\Elucid_EDA.py in ResampleNiiSave(self)`
`     39` 
`     40     def ResampleNiiSave(self):`
`-> 41         dcmItk = dicomread(prepSeg.dcmPath, imgitk=True)`
`     42         nrdItk = nrrdread(prepSeg.nrdPath, imgitk=True) `
`     43         data = [dcmItk, None]`

`AttributeError: type object 'prepSeg' has no attribute 'dcmPath'`

Comment: You are using the class name instead of `self`.

Comment: You need to use ‘self’ inside methods instead of ‘prepSeg’

Comment: @quamrana could you show me the codes?

Comment: @quamrana I understood what you said. I changed all the `prepSeg` mentions into `self` inside the method. But didn't work.

Comment: @Guy Yeah, changed all the class name `prepSeg` into `self` inside the classmethod body. Didn't work.

Comment: “It didn’t work” is not a diagnosis. Please include an error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana 
```
`         4 A = prepSeg(dcmPath, nrdPath)`
`----> 5 A.ResampleNiiSave()`

`~\PycharmProjects\Codes\Elucid_EDA.py in ResampleNiiSave(self)`
`     39  
`     40     def ResampleNiiSave(self):`
---> 41         dcmItk = dicomread(self.dcmPath, imgitk=True) # contains one file multiple slice
     42         nrdItk = nrrdread(self.nrdPath, imgitk=True) # contains single nrrd file
     43         data = [dcmItk, None]

`AttributeError: type object 'prepSeg' has no attribute 'dcmPath'`

Comment: Well, this should work now. You have all the pieces in place. You create ‘A’ as an instance, which creates the dcmPath and nrdPath attributes, then calling ‘A.ResampleNiiSave()’ should just work. Can you restart your IDE?

Comment: @quamrana
Restarted the IDE, but didn't work, still got the following error message:
`AttributeError: type object 'prepSeg' has no attribute 'dcmPath'`

Comment: Perhaps we need to take a step back. Try this: ‘A = prepSeg(dcmFiles[-2],nrdFilesIdx[-2]) ; print(A.dcmPath)’

Comment: simply prints the filepath: 
E:\CAP_Exam_Data\ABCD\dcms\1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.230081008712

Comment: Ok, so ‘A.ResampleNiiSave()’ should work.

Comment: My logic says it should work too. But for some reason I am getting the error: 
~\PycharmProjects\Codes\Elucid_EDA.py in ResampleNiiSave(self)
     39 
     40     def ResampleNiiSave(self):
---> 41         dcmItk = dicomread(self.dcmPath, imgitk=True) # contains one file multiple slice
     42         nrdItk = nrrdread(self.nrdPath, imgitk=True) # contains single nrrd file
     43         data = [dcmItk, None]

`AttributeError: type object 'prepSeg' has no attribute 'dcmPath'`

Comment: Ok, well, the error message is confusing: `AttributeError: type object 'prepSeg' ...` means that you are calling the method on the class and not an instance. You must try: `A = prepSeg(dcmFiles[-2],nrdFilesIdx[-2]); A.ResampleNiiSave()` to make sure that `A` is a proper instance.

Comment: @quamrana These two lines are in the same cell. So I am running them together in order. 
`type(A)` gives: Elucid_EDA.prepSeg ... Elucid_EDA is the name of the .py file from where I am importing the `prepSeg`

Comment: @quamrana I changed all the codes to a single IDE instead of two. Now the code runs as usual without issues. Just to clarify, classes can exist without any return or shall I leave it as it is?

Comment: All functions and methods default to a return of `None`. You can override this with your own `return` if you need to. However, you never need a `return` from an `__init__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you've got yourself in a mess with your IDE.

It is fooling you about what is going on.

Try this code:

```py
class prepSeg():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ''
    def foo(self):
        print(self)
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)


A = prepSeg()
A.foo()
#prepSeg.foo(prepSeg)
```

This produces the output:

```py
<__main__.prepSeg object at 0x04267B70>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\andrew\Python\soMissingAttribute.py", line 12, in <module>
    A.foo()
  File "D:\andrew\Python\soMissingAttribute.py", line 8, in foo
    print(self.b)
AttributeError: 'prepSeg' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Notice `object at 0x...` and the wording of the `AttributeError`. Also it is talking about `b` which is deliberately missing.

If I swap the driver code round:

```py
A = prepSeg()
#A.foo()
prepSeg.foo(prepSeg)
```

I get a different output:

```py
<class '__main__.prepSeg'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\andrew\Python\soMissingAttribute.py", line 13, in <module>
    prepSeg.foo(prepSeg)
  File "D:\andrew\Python\soMissingAttribute.py", line 7, in foo
    print(self.a)
AttributeError: type object 'prepSeg' has no attribute 'a'
```

Now `self` prints: `<class '__main__.prepSeg'>` and the `AttributeError` is about `type object 'prepSeg'` having no attribute `a`.